# php json response with curly bracket

Tags: php, json

The problem is to get an object result instead of array in json.

here is my code :

```
$response = $obj->toArray();
$encoded = json_encode($response, true);
header('Content-type: application/json');
exit($encoded);
```

and the result is somtimes like :

```
[ {"id":"1","value":"COM1"} , {"id":"2","value":"COM2"} ]
```

and I want it a pure json like :

```
{ "0" : {"id":"1","value":"COM1"} , "1" : {"id":"2","value":"COM2"} }
```

Comment: Your "pure JSON" is invalid. The one you are rejecting is, in fact, correct.

Comment: When you use `json_encode` it puts the `[]` and it's in its nature, you cannot change it; the way you read it in output (html page, javascript) is important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
json_encode( $array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT )
```

That will return everything encased in { }